# How to redirect if jwt is not presented in the request using Flask-jwt-extended

Tags: flask, flask-jwt-extended

Is there a built-in way to redirect to login page if user comes without JWT or wrong JWT is used?

```
@api.route('/private', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def protected():
  logged = get_jwt_identity()
  return jsonify(logged_in=logged), 200
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing_default_behavior/

Comment: @NishānWickramarathna I've changed ```@jwt_required(optional=True)``` and added redirect field to the response if no correct JWT was passed. But I supposed to find something as  ```@jwt_required(redirect_to='/login')``` option

Comment: I am not sure if there is an in-built way. If you are wondering about code duplication, you can always use a `before_request` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution would probably be to change the behavior for when no token is present via the `unauthorized_loader`. Something like:

```py
@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def custom_unauthorized_response(_err):
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

If you needed some more fined grained control, you could use a `before_request` in conjunction with `verify_jwt_in_request()`. Or create your own custom decorator, something like:

```py
def jwt_or_redirect():
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            verify_jwt_in_request(optional=True)
            if not get_jwt_identity():
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            else:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorator

    return wrapper
```